Application Insights – an empty SQL event is logged by default
I am using Azure Application Insights configured like:
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(opt =>
{
    opt.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
});

Then I am adding EF Core:
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});

And when viewing the logs in Application Insights I see the following event:

It's almost empty, it only includes the database name and the host name.
How to get rid of this event? I guess it's being logged by EF Core by default somehow…


How to get rid of this event? I guess it's being logged by EF Core by default somehow

Yes, Application Insights is being generated by EF Core's logging by default but might not be necessary for all applications, especially in production environments where it could generate a lot of noise.

To remove these EF Core logging events from Application Insights, you can adjust the logging configuration for EF Core.

EF Core uses the built-in logging framework of .NET, which means you can control its logging behavior using standard logging configuration options.
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options
        .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
            builder.AddFilter((category, level) =>
                category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name && level == LogLevel.Information);
        }))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); // If needed, enables logging of parameter values
});


AddFilter is used to specify which log messages should be accepted. In this case, we only accept log messages from the DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command category at the Information level. This is the category that corresponds to database command logging in EF Core.

EnableSensitiveDataLogging is an optional method that enables logging of parameter values in addition to the SQL commands.
NOTE: Be cautious with this option as it could potentially log sensitive data.


please follow the below approach it will prevent from creating dependencies in Application Insights.
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options
        .AddInterceptors(new MyEmptyDependencyInterceptor());
});


In this approach, MyEmptyDependencyInterceptor is a custom interceptor that you can create to intercept EF Core's commands and prevent them from creating dependencies in Application Insights

public class MyEmptyDependencyInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        // Prevent the command from being executed
        return InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(default);
    }
}


Still the same :(
But the issue is IMO that there is no event logged, only an empty dependency. So maybe the question should be: how to get rid of this SQL dependency?

@bpiec If empty dependency is the only issue, please check my latest updated answer it will be helpful to you.
